# How can I show a wx.TipWindow multiple times?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to show a `wx.TipWindow` at the mouse location when the scroll wheel changes a `RadioBox` item (I want the newly selected item to show at the mouse).

Here is simply what I have:

```
wx.TipWindow(self, self.rdb.GetString(nxt)) <- Works perfectly. Self is an instance of wx.Frame
```

However, if the above line gets called more than once, (ie, I scroll more than once ~5 times) it constantly makes new windows on top of one another. Eventually, the program crashes with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seth\anaconda3\envs\DLC-GPU\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.py", line 989, in _onMouseWheel
    x = evt.GetX()
AttributeError: 'MouseEvent' object has no attribute 'GetX'
```

Can I not get this to work? I tried closing and destroying the `TipWindow` before showing the next one, but same error.

I have thought "why not make my own" but sheesh thats annoying lol.

Code block where `wx.TipWindow` is shown:

```
    def MouseWheel(self, event):
        assert isinstance(event, wx.MouseEvent)
        whlRot = event.GetWheelRotation()

        if whlRot < 0:
            nxt = self.rdb.GetSelection() + 1
            if nxt < self.rdb.GetCount():
                self.rdb.SetSelection(nxt) # Sets the next object in the RadioBox
                wx.TipWindow(self, self.rdb.GetString(nxt))

        if whlRot > 0:
            prv = self.rdb.GetSelection() - 1
            if prv >= 0:
                self.rdb.SetSelection(prv) # Sets the previous object in the RadioBox
                wx.TipWindow(self, self.rdb.GetString(prv))
```

Comment: You haven't given much context, let alone code. That error is out of matplotlib! That said, it's obvious what is selected in a radiobox, so why shout about it? If you must, the easiest way would be to adjust the RadioBox ToolTip, the mouse is already sat on top of it.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, what more would you like? I explained that when the mouse scroll wheel happens, I display a `wx.TipWindow`. That window requires one line of code. If that line of code is executed more than once before its closed, the error is thrown. The fact matplotlib is throwing the error is why I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, secondly, how the heck does `MouseEvent` not have the attribute `GetX` when I can access it myself!? Oh, and the `RadioBox` item changes on mouse wheel scroll, not on click. So the mouse may not be over the `RadioBox`, hence why it would be nice to see what it switched to.

Comment: Clearly, context is everything and you haven't provided any. wxPython `RadioBox` as far as I am aware, normally requires a mouseclick to select one of the options. If you have it doing something else i.e. on mouse scroll, that is where the context comes in. If I'm wrong I'll be happy to eat my words, convince me.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, thanks for getting back. You can programmatically set the option via `RadioBox.SetSelection`, so you do not need to click one of the options for it to become set. This is mentioned in the question posted "...scroll wheel changes RadioBox item...". I added the code where I change this to the question for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer to this that does not require updating wxPython (as this broke other things in the code that isn't mine).

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
 if self.popUp is None:
     self.popUp = wx.TipWindow(self, wht, maxLength=1000000)
 else:
     try: # Try is needed for if the TipWindow is closed by clicking elsewhere
        self.popUp.Show(show=False) # This was the key line. For some reason, hiding the window was required before destroying
        self.popUp.Destroy()
     except:
        pass
    self.popUp = wx.TipWindow(self, wht, maxLength=1000000)
```

This works perfectly and is what I want for the results.

Answer (score 0):

As you say  "...scroll wheel changes RadioBox item..." but that is not a native function of a radiobox, it's something that you have engineered via code that we cannot see.

I assume that it looks something like this:

```
import wx

class RadioBoxFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Radio Box Frame', size=(400, 400))
        
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, pos=(10,10), size=(300,300), style=wx.BORDER_RAISED)
        sampleList = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine']
        self.option=wx.RadioBox(panel, -1, "Select an option", pos=(10, 10), size=wx.DefaultSize, choices=sampleList, majorDimension=3, style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.getOption)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.getWheelOption)

        for i in range(len(sampleList)):
            self.option.SetItemToolTip(i, "Option "+sampleList[i]) 
        
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("Status area")
        self.Show()
        
    def getWheelOption(self, event):
        assert isinstance(event, wx.MouseEvent)
        whlRot = event.GetWheelRotation()

        if whlRot < 0:
            nxt = self.option.GetSelection() + 1
        else:
            nxt = self.option.GetSelection() - 1
        if nxt > self.option.GetCount() - 1:
            nxt = 0
        if nxt < 0:
            nxt = self.option.GetCount() - 1
        self.option.SetSelection(nxt) # Sets the next object in the RadioBox
        txt = "Option " + self.option.GetString(nxt) + " Selected"
        tw = wx.TipWindow(self, txt)
        tw.SetBoundingRect(wx.Rect(1,1,1,1)) #restrict action required to cancel tipwindow
        self.SetStatusText(txt)
        
    def getOption(self, event):
        state1 = self.option.GetSelection()
        txt = self.option.GetString(state1)
        self.SetStatusText(txt+" is Selected")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    RadioBoxFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

Play with this code a bit and see you you are still getting the same error, because using wxPython 4.1.1 on Linux, the code above doesn't give an error. You may need to look at your environment if the above code fails.

Comment: Nope. Error still happens. It happens when you scroll the wheel more than once before clearing the `wx.TipWindow`. Also, I added the code I am using to my question when I posted my previous comment. EDIT: UPGRADING WXPYTHON FIXED IT

Comment: #@Seth Glad to hear you sorted it out.

Comment: Yeah, simply updating it fixed it but opened up new issues.. go figure. I think my next approach is to either create my own, or import the new files of wxPython's TipWindow into the 4.07 version of wxPython. It's seriously annoying lol

Answer (score 0):

I noticed different TipWindow behavior on Windows between wxPython 4.1.0 and 4.1.1. In the 4.1.1 version, the TipWIndow is not be destroyed when moving out of a BoundingRect. Similar issues as described above but with the difference that I experience this only when upgrading to 4.1.1. See snippet below to reproduce this behavior + picture of effect in 4.1.1. Anybody had similar experience and know what the fix is?

```html
import wx


class RadioBoxFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, pos=(10, 10))
        sampleList = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two']
        self.option = wx.RadioBox(panel, -1, "Select an option", pos=(10, 10),
                                  size=wx.DefaultSize, choices=sampleList,
                                  majorDimension=3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.getOption)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.getWheelOption)

        self.Show()

    def getWheelOption(self, event):
        whlRot = event.GetWheelRotation()
        if whlRot < 0:
            nxt = self.option.GetSelection() + 1
        else:
            nxt = self.option.GetSelection() - 1

        if nxt > self.option.GetCount() - 1:
            nxt = 0
        if nxt < 0:
            nxt = self.option.GetCount() - 1

        self.option.SetSelection(nxt)
        txt = "Option " + self.option.GetString(nxt) + " Selected"
        tw = wx.TipWindow(self, txt)
        tw.SetBoundingRect(wx.Rect(1, 1, 1, 1))

    def getOption(self, event):
        state1 = self.option.GetSelection()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    RadioBoxFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image: multiple tip windows not closing]